# Automator: Take screenshot > Prompt rename > Add date and time to name

Tags: finder, applescript, automator, screen-capture

**This is what I need to achieve:**

1. I take a screenshot
2. Automator watches my Screenshot folder for a new file
3. A prompt appears for me to rename the file
4. Date & Time are added after the name I give it

So the result would be: **NewName on 02/04/20 at 3:49:44 PM.png**

How could I set this up?

I've managed to set up a folder action through automator so that it watched my Screenshots folder, prompts me to rename new files, and add the date/time, but I don't like the time format Automator uses.

**Is there a combination of folder action/script that would provide the result shown above?**

Thank you!

Comment: The naming convention you want is not possible.

Comment: The problem with the _date naming convention_, e.g. `02/04/20`, as a _filename_, not a _path filename_ is `/` is a _path delimiter_ and cannot be used as part of the _individual filename_. E.g. `02/04/20` represents multiple _directories/folders_. As to the _time naming convention_, a _file_ can be created with, e.g., `3:49:44 PM`, however it will show as, e.g., `3/49/44 PM` in **Finder**, but `3:49:44 PM` in **Terminal**. This is in part why the _default naming convention_ for screen shots is e.g.: `Screen Shot 2020-04-02 at 10.32.40 AM`

Comment: Also note that renaming a file while it is still in the watched folder will trigger the folder action again.

Comment: @red_menace Yeah to avoid the double trigger of the folder action I have the screenshots saved "Temp Folder", once I rename then via the prompt they are moved to "Screenshots". So how could I maintain the default Screen Shot 2020-04-02 at 10.32.40 AM format except for replacing the "Screen Shot" part with whatever I enter in the prompt?

Comment: To your comment RE: "So how could I maintain the default Screen Shot 2020-04-02 at 10.32.40 AM format except for replacing the "Screen Shot" part with whatever I enter in the prompt?" -- It would be more helpful if you'd include your existing **Automator**  _Watched Folder workflow_ in your OP. That said, one way is to use a **Rename Finder Items** _action_ set to **Replace Text** and set **Find:** `Screen Shot` **in** _basename only_, and under **Options**  check **[√] Show this action when the workflow runs**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming and moving files with other actions in Automator usually involves saving the list of file items to restore later, then adding the other actions using the `Ignore Input` option as needed to keep from mixing up the various results.

If you are using a destination folder for the final result, you can use a workflow something like:

1. **Folder Action** receives files and folders added to { *targetFolder* }
2. **Move Finder Items** { To: *destinationFolder* } (to keep from triggering
   the folder action again)
3. **Set Value of Variable** { Variable: *fileItems* }
4. **Ask For Text** (Ignore Input) (This will be text for the new name)
5. **Set Value of Variable** { Variable: *newName* }
6. **Get Value of Variable** { Variable: *fileItems* } (Ignore Input)
7. **Rename Finder Items** { Replace Text, Find: (*the text "Screen Shot"*)
   in basename only, Replace: (*drag newName variable*) }

Comment: FWIW All the _variable_ type _actions_ are not necessary if under **Options**  check **[√] Show this action when the workflow runs** on the **Rename Finder Items** _action_. Then the new name can be entered there.

Comment: Also, shouldn't "(the text "Screen Shot") in full name," **be** "(the text "Screen Shot") in basename only,"?

Comment: Good point - I tested with the full name option, but if there was a folder with that text in the path it wouldn't end well.  Edited the answer.